# I am having troubles with the scope of a button's listener

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to close a window after executing a function that is not defined in the same file as the window.

I'll try to explain the structure of the classes involved:

there are 2 classes, **Class1.js** and **Class2.js**, in Class1.js there is defined a function  **function1(){}** and **function2(){}** is defined in Class2.js

How it works:

**function2 it's called in Class1.js, openning a window and it receives as parameter function1** like:

function2(function1);

**function1 it's executed when a button is clicked on the new window, defined also in Class2.js:**

```
var win = new Ext.Window({  
    id: 'win that I want to close',
    .  
    .  
    .   
    buttons: [{  
              id: 'button that activates function1',  
              text: 'button1',  
              listeners: {  
                    click:  function1  
                  },  
                  scope: win  
              },
              .
              .
              .
             ]

});  
win.show();
```

In Class1.js, at function1 I try to do:

```
if(this.id == 'win that I want to close'){
    this.close();
}
```

But **the scope that I get is the one from the button in the new window, not the window's scope, so I cannot close it.**

I know that my explanation is quite bad, but is not easy to explain and I am totally stuck at this point.

Congratulations you if you tryied to undestand what I wrote, you are very brave! and Thank you for your help!

Comment: Pls try to explain better. You are in page 2 and you want to close a Window defined and opened in page1 ? Makes sense to you?

Comment: Actually yes, the second "page" it's and emergent "page", defined in its own class (class2), using a function from the class1, and called from tha class1.

Comment: You should not use Ext.getCmp('id') in most cases.

Comment: @Javier please post your solution as the answer and accept it so that it doesn't look like this question is unanswered.

Comment: Ok, now I think it is answered, doesn't it? I'm still getting use to this webpage procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution:

```
listeners: {
    'click': {
        fn: function1,
        scope: {
            winid: 'win that I want to close'
        }
    }
}
```

And with that I can get the element with `Ext.getCmp(this.winid)` from `Class1`.